# Adding "pdi-google-spreadsheet-plugin-master" to pentaho's Kettle Spoon

Tags: pentaho-spoon, pdi

I want to add plugin "pdi-google-spreadsheet-plugin-master" to pentaho's Kettle Spoon. I have download "pdi-google-spreadsheet-plugin-master" and unziped it to "C:\Pentaho\data-integration\plugins" but I don't know from where I can use this plugin in kettle spoon.
I have also tried to copy that "D:\Pentaho\data-integration\plugins\steps", but unable to see or find how to use that plugin in transormation or in jobs.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to build what you downloaded.
Building
This Plugin is built with Maven.

```
$ git clone git@github.com:GlobalTechnology/pdi-google-spreadsheet-plugin.git
$ cd pdi-google-spreadsheet-plugin
$ mvn package
```

This will produce a Kettle plugin in `target/pdi-google-spreadsheet-plugin-{version}.zip`.

This file can be extracted into your Pentaho Data Integrations plugin directory.